# Why do I get maximum update depth exceeded for rendered screen?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I get an error for one component that Maximum update depth exceeded, I tried to figure out what cause the issue and I fail. Can You please look at the console comment and the code and suggest where shall I search for problem solving ?

[image]

```
export const LineAlertsScreen = () => {
    const { useTranslationFunc } = useTranslationFacade();
    const { lineAlertsData, getLineAlertsData } =
        useContext(LineDetailsContext);
    const { handlePushToProperLocationDependingOnAlertValues } =
        useContext(AlertsContext);
    const { lineId } = useParams<RouterParamsModel>();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'));

    useEffect(() => {
        if (lineId) {
            getLineAlertsData(lineId);
        }
    }, [lineId]);

    const dateTranslation = useTranslationFunc('Data');
    const lineTranslation = useTranslationFunc('Linia');
    const typeTranslation = useTranslationFunc('Typ');
    const lineKmTranslation = useTranslationFunc('Kilometr');
    const descriptionTranslation = useTranslationFunc('Opis');

    
    return (
        <div>
            <LinesGlobalToolbar />
            <StyledAlertsContentWrapper>
                {matches && <SideNavigationPanelLines />}
                <StyledBackgroundGreyDiv>
                    <StyledBackgroundContainerDiv>
                        <LineHeader lineId={lineId} />
                        <StyledBackgroundContentContainerDiv>
                            <StyledHeaderDiv>
                                {useTranslationFunc('Lista alertów')}
                            </StyledHeaderDiv>
                            <AlertList
                                columns={columns}
                                data={lineAlertsData ?? []}
                                onRowClick={
                                    handlePushToProperLocationDependingOnAlertValues
                                }
                            />
                        </StyledBackgroundContentContainerDiv>
                    </StyledBackgroundContainerDiv>
                </StyledBackgroundGreyDiv>
            </StyledAlertsContentWrapper>
            {!matches && <LinesBottomNavigationMobile />}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: You will find this (and everything else) *much* easier to debug if you switch to using unminified code outside of production

Comment: I have noticed that matches used as useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md')) from MUI cause the issue. When I comment-out matches screen renders properly. 
What is wrong with that ? I use it as in other places and works well there